# C# XML serialization of sequential ID

Tags: xml, serialization, c#-4.0

I have a C# class that is to be serialized as XML. One of the sub nodes has a sequence id which is incremented. The following code works.

```
public class PlansSummary
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public List<Plan> Plans { get; set; } = new List<Plan>();

    public string ToXml()
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(this.GetType());
        using (var stringXml = new StringWriter())
        {
            serializer.Serialize(stringXml, this);
            return stringXml.ToString();
        }
    }
}

public class Plan
{
    private static int _sequenceCount = 1;

    public Plan()
    {
        _sequenceCount++;
    }

    //// In this property, 'set' must exist and be public for XmlSerializer to work
    public int sequence { get; set; } = _sequenceCount;
    public DateTime planStartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime planEndDate { get; set; }
}
```

But there's nothing to stop the next developer using my class and useing the set option on the sequence property.  I can't make sequence private or read only because this will stop sequence appearing in the XML. Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you implement an empty setter?

```
public class Plan
{
    private static int _sequenceCount = 0;
    private int _sequenceReturn = 0;

    public Plan()
    {
        _sequenceCount++;
        _sequenceReturn = _sequenceCount;
    }

    public int sequence
    {
        get
        {
            return _sequenceReturn;
        }
        set { }
    }

    public DateTime planStartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime planEndDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: No, infact that does something unexpected. If I have four Plan objects in my Plans list then the sequence number is 5 for all four of them.

Comment: I updated the codeblock - If you implement an instance variable (in this case _sequenceReturn) alongside the empty setter, you should find the sequence works as originally intended.